# How can I include javascript file in the rails assets pipeline?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I have created a new ruby on rails project using the command : rails new [project_name].

Further, I want to create javascript files, so I can control my view elements.
For this, I've created a new js file and placed it in the app->assets->javascripts->apple_pay.js

Currently the appe_pay.js implementation is just for testing :

```
console.log("test")
```

Also, my application.js, used like a manifest file, looks like this :

```
//= require_tree .
```

When I run the project using rails server command, I'm expecting to see the message displayed on the console, but it's not, any ideea ?

Comment: Anything in your JS console in browser?

Comment: nothing, I think I am missing something, or just I dont understand how things are working using rails, I am a beginner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

find: `config/initializers/assets.rb`
Then: `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w[your_file.js]`

noticing that as it's out of application.js you need to include it inside your views using:

```
javascript_include_tag :your_file
```

Save & Restart your server :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer helped me to find the solution in my case: I had to add : <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %> in my .erb file, because in the application.js i was requiring the whole tree.

Comment: Great to know that, I wrote the javascript_include_tag based on HAML not html.erb sorry for that but I'm happy that your issue was solved.

Answer (score -2):

If you are not install "jquery-rails" then first install the gem and require file also add in application.js

//= require file_name